# How to get the output of train_on_batch in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a GAN.  I would like to be able to capture the predicted output of my generator when I call train_on_batch.  This way I could use that output to train the discriminator.  Right now I have to call predict on my generator to generate new training samples.  This is less efficient.  I saw a way to do it with an older version by adding a metric but it appears they removed it from the latest version.  I am using Keras included with Tensorflow 2.4.1.